# How to stop loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, converters

I'm a step away from completing my binary converter, though it keeps on repeating, it's and endless loop.

```
def repeat1():
    if choice == 'B' or choice == 'b':
        while True:
            x = input("Go on and enter a binary value: ")
            try:
                y = int(x, 2)
            except ValueError:
                print("Please enter a binary value, a binary value only consists of 1s and 0s")
                print("")
    else:
        if len(x) > 50:
            print("The number of characters that you have entered is", len(x))
            print("Please enter a binary value within 50 characters")
            z = len(x)
            diff = z - 50
            print("Please remove", diff, "characters")
            print(" ")
        else:
            print(x, "in octal is", oct(y)[2:])
            print(x, "in decimal is", y)
            print(x, "in hexidecimal is", hex(y)[2:])
            print(" ")
            def tryagain1(): 
                print("Type '1' to convert from the same number base")
                print("Type '2' to convert from a different number base")
                print("Type '3' to stop")
                r = input("Would you like to try again? ")
                print("")
                if r == '1':
                    repeat1()
                    print("")
                elif r == '2':
                    loop()
                    print("")
                elif r == '3':
                print("Thank you for using the BraCaLdOmbayNo Calculator!")
            else:
                print("You didn't enter any of the choices! Try again!")
                tryagain1()
                print("")
                tryagain1()
```

I'm looking for a way to break the loop specifically on the line of code "elif r== '3':. I already tried putting 'break', but it doesn't seem to work. It keeps on asking the user to input a binary value even though they already want to stop. How do I break the loop?

Comment: (Assuming this is python). Why are you defining `tryagain1` function within another function?

Comment: It is indeed python, I'm using python 3. Anyway, I did that in order for the user to have an easier time. Though I think the root of the problem is how to turn the `while True` to false.

Comment: Does your code indented exactly like it is presented here?

Comment: The right way to leave `while(True)` loop is `break`. You should fix your codestyle so that one could understand what is going on and then use `break`.

Answer (score 1):

```
            elif r == '3':
                 print("Thank you for using the BraCaLdOmbayNo Calculator!")
                 return 0

        else:
            print("You didn't enter any of the choices! Try again!")
            choice = try again()
            if choice == 0:
               return 0
            print("")
            tryagain1()
```

`return` is suppose to be used at the end of the Function or code when you have nothing else to do